# Importance of OOP concepts? Are they really used to full extent?

Tags: oop

The question seems pretty simple, and so is the answer. I am a developer who recently started working. So far I had taken few bachelor and master level courses on OOP. And yet I am not comfirtable and confident with OOP concepts. Recently, I was searching for employment opportunities and I found that many employers were keen to know how much confident I am on OOP concepts.

I have a very strong theorotical knowledge on OOP concepts. Although this theorotical knowledge is helping me in clearing the interviews and getting a job but when it comes to implementation I am getting dumb. If you ask me what is reflection then you will get a perfect answer from me, but if someone asks me why and where do we use it, then I get fumbled.

Now I really want to know what I should do when I am not getting an opportunity to implement all or most of the OO concepts in my projects.

Also I really feel with all the latest development tools and programming environments, many of the programmers are getting pampered to use already built components, frameworks and libraries and this is might create a vacuum of good architects.

I want to become a successful architect and for that I think I must be very strong in this area.

Then I thought of learning NHibernate where you will be dealing with objects entirely.

Now what I need is few valuable tips that would help me in grasping all or most of the OOP concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like you're missing real programming experience. Nothing will substitute that.

Go working, exercise, read, learn from your more experienced colleagues. Eventually you'll get it.

As for very advanced tools, you are correct. They produce code monkeys in ever increasing amounts. If you see it right now you are on a good start. Just keep to the path. Good architects will always be needed and valued.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start looking at design patterns. Knowing the when, how and why of using OOP is more valuable than knowing OOP itself.

Frameworks are great and I don't fault people for using them. But, there is still a lot of room for great architects in this space. Exploit the gap of programmers knowing how to use them, but not why or when. Frameworks quickly become a hammer looking for a nail for many developers. Open source is your friend here - dive into the source code and learn them from the inside out so you really understand what's being done and why.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you learn the "conceptual" side of development from school and the "applications" side from real experience.  There is no substitute for working on the job; no matter how much schooling I've had it never equates to what I've learned doing the real work.  This is why it's also a good idea to get an internship in college if you're able.

As for the value of OOP itself, I find that it's most useful in large projects and in team projects. The whole point is to break down the solution into workable "conceptual" elements which makes intercommunication between team members easier as well as visualizing the solution. Visualization is the other big pro to OOP.

One thing to note about OOP IMHO is that entry level developers tend to overuse a lot of the OOP concepts. Not everything requires inheritance. Design patterns are extremely useful but also shouldn't be over applied.  Look at your problem and first try to think of a solution on your own then compare it to known patterns and see if they provide a better answer. Simplicity can't be overrated.

Also, playing with tools like UML editors and Mind Mappers (such as [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/)) are helpful in getting into the right frame of mind.

Check and see if there are any programming groups around you too; I find it's a good way to meet people that you can talk programming with and another advantage of OOP is its much easier to communicate programming ideas with.

Answer (score 1):

Your next stop should be to look into design patterns (Applied OO).  For an introductory text, check out [Headfirst Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. To some extent I've grown up with Object programming, I've evolved as the various frameworks have evolved, I'd never before considered how it would feel to come to a landscape where so many sophisticated frameworks already exist. Their very presence tends to inhibit that degree of fumbling and stumbling and generallly getting it wrong that leads to deeper understanding.

My perception though is that serious development is still a matter of good design, it's not all just fill-in-the-gaps, hey IOC framwork tell me what to do, programming.

You can enhance your theoretic knowlege by studying the "how" of the framworks you use. But I guess what you need is practical experience, can't comment upon what's open to you in your place of work, but if you can't get it there you may need to do some "hobbyist" or open source development.

One thing I would recommend is trying to get involved in design discussions, try to get your designs reviewed by experienced developers. With any luck they may even say: "hey why didn't you use reflection there ..."

Answer (score -1):

It is the 'thinking' that is important, in OOP one needs to change thinking
while going about programming/developing in oop environment or using OOP
paradigm.

I have faced many a times this question myself: why use OOPL or
Object Oriented Programming Language when I can develop software in Procedural
Programming Language? Why use OOP methodology at all? What benefit does it have
what other non-oop doesn't?

I read from many sources (numerous books and articles on the subject to name!)
to trace the real reason, to hit the fundamental underlying idea or principle
for its being there as a paradigm of software engineering. I think what I found
is simple and that's why I suggest to bring a change in thinking.

If we look around we see things that surround us and the things we interact
with, directly or indirectly. We recognize them with names, we gave them.
Whatever the things are, either they exist in real plane or conceptual plane
and we 'know' them 'recognize' them and interact with them. And importantly we
'name' them. This naming is important because to interact with the 'things' and
for that knowledge of that interaction we need 'Names'.

What have you eaten today?  Chocolate and coffee. So you have 'interacted' with
chocolate and coffee. Now Chocolate and coffee are edibles we have (humans)
have given names and with those names we recognize them. And also, we, in our
knowledge of our interaction with them - lets say keeping record of our
interaction with chocolate and coffee, know them with names as having
interacted with.

Interaction is a general term I am using here. Actually in our case, in the
example, you have performed an 'action' - eating. Through 'eating' action you
have interacted with chocolate and coffee. Now think this way, you, chocolate,
coffee are entities in the real world through an action came in interaction.
You may say a 'Process'.

What course Alice has enrolled for?  Computer Science.
Computer Science does not have a real existence in the world in the sense a man
exists or a tree or a house, or coffee cup or other 'tangible things' exist. It
is a subject, 'conceptual thing'. The study of computer science has some
'topics' to be studied (or to have interaction with through our mental
faculty/processes)e.g discrete mathematics, design and analysis of algorithms,
Data Structure etc. Together they are named, as a subject of study, 'Computer
Science'. Now Alice 'study' (interaction) Computer Science.What is happening
here? OK, if We now think this way and say that Alice is a thing, ***an object***.
Computer Science is a thing, ***an object***.

Coffee is *an object*. Chocolate is *an object*. You, again, are *an object*. We find
that *objects* interacting with *objects*. Fantastic! One may exclaim! That's the
real world scenario! Actually it is a generalization reached through
***Abstraction***.

It is nothing but -at the surface level at least- **naming with
meaning**. Or you can say ***'meaningful naming'***. It is a process. It is so  natural
and obvious to us that we simply overlook it.

In OOP we simply have to bring ourselves to this form of thinking process,
knowing and reminding ourselves that "Objects interact with Objects". Oh!
There are more than thinking only this. You have to remember that an object
may interact with itself! Think of you, what are you doing when you are
thinking? Yeah! And there is another very important thing I shall come to
in due time. Though I think it is obvious. But in due time. OK. What we
really do with computers? Actually we solve problems. Particularly those
problems which we try to do or solve in our minds. In broad sense we are
simulating mental processes in a machine, so designed by us. Remember AI is
still a far off thing in reality and there are debates both scientific and
philosophical, on whether a computer can become Intelligent at all. Another
way of putting it whether a computer can really simulate a real mental
process. But that's not for us to take here. Leave it!

If we want to solve problems in real life through a computing device we
would like to go as closely in representing the real life as possible.There
comes the term in OOP 'real life modelling'. It can be seen that in solving
real life problems, be it launching a space shuttle, or keeping the customer
and product sale information for processing we do abstraction and do
calculation, which is another form of abstract process, in turn we deal with
objects mentally, in our mind. So we represent real life objects (conceptual
objects such as numbers) in abstraction and deal with them with abstract
processes, as in mathematics. In computer too we would like to represent
objects and also like to represent processes in the form of objects. So here
comes the Object Orientation so to speak to software engineering. Now comes
that 'due time' to deal with another aspect of OO.

To go back to our example, What did you eat? Eating is an action, a form of
interaction. Which can be thought of as process which again can be thought of
as an Object, like a processes is thought of and represented as 'function' or
'routine' or 'procedure' in Non-OOPL. In OOP we can represent (abstract away)
eating as a process embodied as an object.  Similarly studying is an object. In
the same line of thinking 'thing' and 'process' both be thought of as objects
and be represented in virtual plane which is computer memory. Therefore
Alice-an Object-Studies-an object-Computer Science-an Object is valid in OOP
parlance as far as our argument goes.

Can we write a piece of code here? Lets try.

```
class Alice {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String stdID;
    private Course courseOfStudy;
    ... other codes...
    public void studies(Course sub) {
        courseOfStudy=sub;
    }
    ...
    public Course getStudyCourse() {
        return courseOfStudy;
    }
}
class Course {
    codes....
}
```

This way in OOP (here Java code) one can go about writing codes. I have just
given a simplistic coding. One can come up with better coding and design
approach depending on the software in mind to be written. In OOP design is very
important. So in thinking which I mentioned at the beginning the change should
be brought in. That's important! I prefer to go this way when it comes to OOPL
or OOAD, "everything is object".

Well that's what I wanted to say. You may or may not like it but comment and
say your mind.

Comment: You hit me with "GIANT WALL OF TEXT"! It wasn't very effective... I hit you with "Downvote"! It's super effective!